# Element.innerHTML is too expensive to run, need alternatives

Tags: performance, innerhtml

Recently I encounter an issue while profiling my JS code and found out a very small function in the code which took 3-10ms. After investigation, I found out the function `Element.innerHTML` is the one who took almost all the CPU time when called 1-2 times inside this function.

For example: `element1.innerHTML = "<span>text</span>"`.

I am searching for an alternative to reduce CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

If you can **ignore** using Element.innerHTML please do. it is super expensive. Instead, use `document.createElement` and `Element.appendChild` instead it.

I converted this code `element1.innerHTML = "<span>text</span>"` to this code:

```js
var element2 = doc.createElement('span');
element2.innerText = "text";
element1.appendChild(element2);
```

When I did this change in both places I dropped the CPU from each innerHTML usage from 1.5ms to 0.01ms, and even 0ms in most cases.

Then I have a need to add NO_BREAK sign (" ") in different locations that existed in the old code but all the suggestions I got were to use `innerHTML` for this sign, which will add the CPU time I want to prevent.

The solution to this is using:

```js
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0'))
```

which will do the same effect without `innerHTML`. Even using `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` is parsing the HTML and will take more CPU time, so I tried to ignore the use of it as well.

I hope it helps.